# Do pop-ups really work in Flexviewer 2.4?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api

I am trying to configure pop-ups using this code:

```
<layer label="Lansdslide Layers" type="dynamic" visible="true" alpha=".75"
                url="http://yoururl/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hazards/SR2/MapServer/"/>
                <sublayer id="1" popupconfig="popups/PopUp_Historic_Landslide_Points.xml"/>
                <sublayer id="2" popupconfig="popups/PopUp_Scarps.xml"/>
                <sublayer id="3" popupconfig="popups/PopUp_Scarps_Flanks.xml"/>
```

that call simple xmls like PopUp_Demographics_BlockGroups.xml found in the sample flexviewer, but with the fields named appropriately for my layers

I've also tried following this [esri forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/29456-PopUps-in-2.3.1-using-joined-data) with closing the sublayer element and get the error:

```
http response status: 200
```

Fault code: Client.CouldNotDecode

Fault info: Error #1085

Fault details: null

Does anyone have a url that shows pop-ups really working?

Comment: and your sublayer ids are the same as your layer ids?

Comment: I am using popups successfully - but I am not using sublayers

Comment: yes they are.  I've also tried not using sublayers, and defining the sublayer id=0 (as is says in the forum) and still can't get it to work?

Comment: I have problems with JUST some layers also. If I find a fix I will let you know.

Comment: So I go it to work without sublayers, there was an error in my syntax. But now it looks like fields in pop-ups are restricting to only 11 characters? also see: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/29477-Pop-Ups-with-FlexViewer-2.3?p=149524&posted=1#post149524

Comment: There also appears to be a limitation in the number of fields that your are allowed to display in pop-ups, which is 11.  Where can we change this in the code?

Comment: guess there's a know bug in 2.4 with Pop-ups
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/36513-2.4-PopUp-scrollbar-bug

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the closing slash on the url line.  The layer tag doesn't close (on sublayers) until after the last sublayer. That is the closing slash for the layer tag.

```
code: 
<layer label="Lansdslide Layers" type="dynamic" visible="true" alpha=".75"
                url="http://yoururl/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hazards/SR2/MapServer/">
                <sublayer id="1" popupconfig="popups/PopUp_Historic_Landslide_Points.xml"/>
                <sublayer id="2" popupconfig="popups/PopUp_Scarps.xml"/>
                <sublayer id="3" popupconfig="popups/PopUp_Scarps_Flanks.xml"/>
</layer>
```

[image: sublayer]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but resolved it by identifying that some of the fields I declared in the XML did not match the fields provided by the service.  In particular within the title tag, I had indicated {NAME} when in fact the field provided by the services was {STATE}.  That change fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Popups work well just be sure to note that if your table of contents (in arcmap) looks like this:

Data Frame:

> Layer Group
>   Layer Group
>   Shapefile1
>   Layer Group
>   Shapefile2

then your sublayers in the config.xml will look like this: